# Android Ringtone Picker Spinner

Tags: android, ringtone, android-spinner

I'm trying to make a spinner from Ringtone manager and it's giving me some funny results. THe spinner is coming up fine pulling the ringtone results... but each ringtone result has a radio button...? And when I select a ringtone and run the onItemSelected... it give me nothing and doesn't toast... Any thoughts?

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mRingtoneManager2 = new RingtoneManager(this); //adds ringtonemanager
    mRingtoneManager2.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE); //sets the type to ringtones
    mRingtoneManager2.setIncludeDrm(true); //get list of ringtones to include DRM

    mCursor2 = mRingtoneManager2.getCursor(); //appends my cursor to the ringtonemanager

    startManagingCursor(mCursor2); //starts the cursor query

    //prints output for diagnostics
    String test = mCursor2.getString(mCursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE));
    Log.d(null, test, null);

    String[] from = {mCursor2.getColumnName(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX)}; // get the list items for the listadapter could be TITLE or URI

    int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};

    // create simple cursor adapter
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =
      new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mCursor2, from, to );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
    // get reference to our spinner
    s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinner1);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
        int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int pos = s.getSelectedItemPosition(); 
    Toast.makeText(this, pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Forgot to set my s.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);... DUH! Well if anyone wnats a ringtones spinner here is the code... just rember to add: s.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);